# PHP Loop - skip certain lines

Tags: php, loops

I have a very large text file with over 100,000 lines in it. I need to collect/skip a set number of lines: loop through lines 1-100, skip lines 101-150, read lines 151-210, skip lines 211-300 (for example).

I have the following code

```
$lines = file('file.txt');
$counter = 0;

foreach ($lines as $lineNumber => $line) {

    $counter++;

    if ($counter < 101) {
         //Do update stuff
    }

    if ($counter < 102 && $counter > 151) {
         //Skip these lines
    }

    if ($counter < 152 && $counter > 211) {
         //Do update stuff
    } 
}
```

Is there a better way to skip over many lines of an array's output?

Comment: Not a good idea to have a large file in memory

Comment: Don't use foreach in this situation, use for and utilize the counter

Comment: Read file line by line with `fread`

Comment: Do your skip lines interval is fixed or dynamic???

Comment: The original idea was to skip lines after I iterated over a line that didn't match criteria. example; line began with A, I'd get the following 50 lines. If I iterate a line that starts with B, I'd ignore the next X amount of lines until I crossed an A again. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: You definitely need `fgets` ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, move to `fgets`, it is memory efficient way. You don't need to have all the array in memory. As for conditions, just combine all your conditions with `or` operator and don't add condition for skipping, it's useless.

```
if ($counter < 101 || ($counter >= 151 && $counter <= 210) || add another pediods here) {
     //Do update stuff
}
```

P.S. you have a mistake in your conditions, `($counter < 102 && $counter > 151)` is always `false` as well as the other one.

Comment: Using fgets, can I utilize 'w' instead of 'r' so I can write to the file once I've done my logic handling?

Comment: You are the driver) You can, of course. Use `fseek` to walk in it.

Comment: @AdamA: Not if you value your data. If you want to use `fgets`, write your updated data to a second file. (You can move it over top of the input file once your processing loop is done.)